# 16進数を10進数に変換するテーブル表

Tags: perl

perlでテーブル表を作成するとき、行と列の項目はどういう基準で決定しますか？
項目ごとのデータを入れたいとき、どのようにすればよいですか。
下記のコードでは仕組みは分かりませんが、行と列は分かれております。

```
open (my $f, ">", "table.txt") or die "cannot open textfile : $!\n";
printf $f "%4s", "";
for ( my $item = 0 ; $item < 16 ; $item++ ) {
　　printf $f "%4X ", $item;
}
for ( my $num16 = 0 ; $num16 <=1023 ; $num16++ ) {
　　printf $f "\n%3X ", $num16;
　　printf $f "%04d ", $num16;
}
close($f);
```

Comment: 項目毎というイメージならば2次元配列を使うといいかと思います。

Comment: コードを見る限り[こちらの質問](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/8924)で得た回答を元に作業を進めているように見受けられますが、 「仕組みは分かりませんが」の状態なのであれば、まずは回答のコードがどのような処理を行っているか理解することから始めた方が良いと思います。

Comment: 質問の意図が読み取れないので、上記のコードだと何が問題で、質問者の方はどうしたいのか(どうなってほしいのか)を書いてもらえれば回答できるかもしれません。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。現在、16進数のFFFFまでを10進数に変換するテーブル表をテキストファイルに出力するプログラムを作成中です。二次元配列だと処理が遅く、二重ループの処理が本を読んでも分かりにくいです。質問のコードだと、縦一列にしか変換した内容が表示できず、FF*FFの表になりません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 行と列の項目はどういう基準で決定しますか？

よくわからない部分がありますけど、
今１６進数を１０進数に変換するテーブルということなので、

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F
0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
1  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31
...
A 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175
```

のようなものを想定していると思いますので、
列名は、０～Ｆで行名は、０から１６毎の１６進数でいいかと思います。

こういう縦・横の（つまり２次元の）データは２次元配列で保持するといいかと思います。
Perl でいう配列は１次元配列で、２次元配列は配列(の参照)の配列というような形で実現します。(Ｃ言語で言えばダブルポインタで実現するもののような感じです。)
この場合の具体的な初期化は例えば次のようにします。

```
my @table = ();
for(my $i=0; $i < 1024; $i += 16){#１６要素ずつ追加
    push(@table, [$i..($i+15)]);#配列の最後に配列(例[0..15]０から１５の要素を持つ配列)を追加する
}
```

そうすると、

```
print $table[0xA][0x1];#Ａの１の要素(つまり0xA1を意味する）１６１が表示される。
$table[0xA][0x1] = 161;#Ａの１の要素に１６１を代入する。
```

のように行と列で扱えるようになります。